# Quick way to check if all items in a Ruby array are unique

Tags: ruby

I'm looking for a quick and easy way to check if all the items in an array are unique.

```
unique = ['one', 'two']
unique = []
not_unique = ['one', 'one', 'two']
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
# As simple as possible:
not_unique == not_unique.uniq

# or perhaps
not_unique.size == not_unique.uniq.size
```

Answer (score 7):

```
array & array == array
```

is another option.

Answer (score 1):

```
require 'set'
arr = [1,2,3]
arr.to_set.length == arr.length
```

or as Larsenal points out:

```
arr.uniq == arr
```